# Copying entire contents of folder including subfolders to destination

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible to move .js files from my local machine to an ec2 development environment and am having an issue copying the entire folder structure.

I am using the following task to move the files and seem to be running into an issue where only the files directly in the dist folder are getting copied.  I need to copy the entire folder including the child files and folders to the destination folder.

```
- name: Copy each file over that matches the given pattern
    copy:
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: "/home/admin/microservice/dist"
      owner: "admin"
      group: "admin"
      force: "yes"
      recurse: "true"
      mode: 0755
    with_fileglob:
      - "/Users/myfolder/WebStormProjects/project/microservice/dist/*.js"
```

I need to copy the entire folder contents from the source to the destination, including subfolders and files?  What can I do to fix this task to make this happen?

Comment: check the `syncrononize` module  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/synchronize_module.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `copy` module, the solution to your problem would be much more complicated than you think, because:

- you can't match a directory and `*.js` files in a single globbing operation,
- even if you could, you can't use the same "copy" operation to copy the file as well as create a directory (notice: create directory, not copy! as the latter would imply copying with all the files).

You'd need to handle the directories and files separately (see an implementation in the [first revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51299769/1)).

---

With `rsync`, the solution is much more concise and requires only setting appropriate filters `--include='*/' --include='*.js' --exclude='*'`.

The `synchronize` task implementing this in Ansible:

```
- synchronize:
    src: /source/Users/myfolder/WebStormProjects/project/microservice/dist/
    dest: /home/admin/microservice/dist/
    rsync_opts:
      - --include=*/
      - --include=*.js
      - --exclude=*
```

<sup>Note 1: it is important not to add quotes for the filtered values in `rsync_opts`.</sup>

<sup>Note 2: you might still need to set the appropriate ownership and permissions.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

First using copy module here shouldn't be ideal as "The copy module recursively copy facility does not scale to lots (>hundreds) of files. For alternative, see `synchronize` module, which is a wrapper around rsync."

[copy module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/copy_module.html)

[synchonize module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/synchronize_module.html)

However you can perform as below using copy module::

```
   copy:
       src: "{{ item }}"
       dest: /home/admin/microservice/dist
   with_lines: "find /home/admin/microservice/dist -type f -name *.js "
```

Similarly you can try with "synchronize" module as below::

```
  synchronize:
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: /home/admin/microservice/dist
   with_lines: "find /home/admin/microservice/dist -type f -name *.js "
```

If you want to retain the Directory layout, You can do it as below::

In Step1=> You will copy the necessary pattern files in parent directory structure into a temp directory.

Step2=>Then you need to copy the temp directory into the destination. After wards you can delete the temp directory or whatever your use case is.

`- name: copy pattern files and directory into a temp directory
   shell: find . -type f -name "*.js" | cpio -pvdmB /temp/dir/
     args:
       chdir: "/Users/myfolder/WebStormProjects/project/microservice/dist/"
  - name: Copy the temp directory recursively to destination directory
    copy:
       src: "/temp/dir/"
       dest: "/home/admin/microservice/dist/"
       owner: "admin"
       group: "admin"
       force: "yes"
       mode: 0755`

Comment: Would this also account for copying the folder as well?

Comment: In my example, it only copies the pattern files recursively from the source directory into destination. It is not coping the directory structure. If you want to copy the directory structure you have to optimize the command or playbook as per  your requirement.

Comment: I am running it right now.  This is close.  I do notice that it is only copying the files and not and folders as well.  I am drawing a blank on how to make it copy folders as well.

Comment: I have edited my answer on, How you can perform while retaining the parent directory structure layout.